# In PHP, can the local array variable in class member functions referenced by class member variable?

Tags: php, variables, pointers, reference, local

```
class A {
    public $a;
    public function foo() {
        $b = array("a", "b");   
        $this->a = &$b;
    }
}
```

what will happen?

`$b` is a `pointer` to an `array` and when the function `foo()` exits, `$b` disappears and array remains there?

If array also disappears, `$a` will lose reference to it.

Can anyone explain it for me?

Comment: Try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php). I think it should help clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is something like this:

And Yes you can! Here you assign `array $b` as a reference to `$a` and change `$b`. Then you output `$a` and it's the same as the changed `$b`!

```
<?php 

    class A {

        public $a;

        function foo() {
            $b = array("a", "b");
            $this->a = &$b;

            $b[] = "c";
            print_r($b);
            unset($b);
            print_r($b);
            print_r($this->a);
        }

        function foo2() {
            print_r($this->a);
        }
    }

    $test = new A();
    $test->foo();
    $test->foo2();

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) //$b
Notice: Undefined variable: b in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\index.php on line 27  //after unset $b
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )  //$a from the function foo
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )  //$a from the function foo2
```

UPDATE after Comment:

(with global variable)

```
<?php

    global $c;
    $c = 42;

    $d = &$c;
    $c = 2;
    unset($c);    

    echo $d;


?>
```

Output:

```
2
```